# How to filter out Eureka clients in Eureka server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, server, microservices, netflix-eureka

**Problem description:**

We have 100+ springboot services running in different environments: dev, uat, **prod**, etc,
and for each one **we have eureka servers running up for registering those micro services**, no problem with that, after deploying a service it gets registered and works just fine,
but when we run a service **locally** it gets registered in the eureka server in prod,

**I would like to avoid that somehow,** so is there any advice for doing that?

#### is there a way to set up my Eureka servers for not registering a service based its parameters or something like that?

**Notes**: I don't want to manually set properties like `registerWithEureka: false` because we have just too many services.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

For the services that you don;t want them to register, remove @EnableDiscoveryClient from the services. @EnableDiscoveryClien lives in spring-cloud-commons and picks the implementation on the classpath. This will stop your services from getting discovered but then you won;t be able to make the Feign calls to other services and take the benefit of load balancing your calls.

Comment: thanks for your response Amit, but in this case removing an annotation from a client service is not what I'm looking for, rather I'm looking to another solution that could give me control over the Eureka server for filtering out registered services or a similar solution

Comment: Another alternate that you can try is to filter the IP. See if this works for you. Put this config at bootstrap.yml
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      preferredNetworks:
        - 192.168
        - 10.0